# Will my progress save as a guest account?

Tags: minecraft-education-edition

If I have been playing in creative mode in a guest account in Minecraft, will my progress be saved if I sign in? I have looked at other people’s answers, but so far I have only found things about survival mode.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't minecraft not have any save in the cloud functionality? Like if you played on a computer, whatever the account you were logged in, your save is on that computer. If its an online play, well your progress is on that server. IDK if that would be different for the education edition.

Comment: It is based on Local saves, but you are required to sign in to play (otherwise you get a trial). @Fredy31